# Start new activity

Tags: java, android

```
package com.csfv3.maps.views.overlays;

import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.csfv3.maps.tileManagement.TilesManager;
    import com.csfv3.poi.POI;

    public class POIOverlay extends MapOverlay
    {
protected Bitmap poiMarker;
protected Paint bitmapPaint = new Paint();
protected Paint textPaint = new Paint();
protected ArrayList<POI> points = new ArrayList<POI>();
protected ArrayList<Point> absPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

Context context;

public POIOverlay(TilesManager tilesManager, Context context, Bitmap poiMarker)
{
    super(tilesManager);

    this.context = context;
    this.poiMarker = poiMarker;

    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(30);
}

@Override
protected void drawOverlay(Canvas canvas, int x, int y)
{
    for (POI poi : points)
    {
        if (!poi.isVisible()) continue;

        Point poiPos = tilesManager.lonLatToPixelXY(poi.getLongitude(), poi.getLatitude());
        int finalX = poiPos.x + x;
        int finalY = poiPos.y + y;

        canvas.drawBitmap(poiMarker, finalX - poiMarker.getWidth() / 2, finalY - poiMarker.getHeight() / 2, bitmapPaint);
        // canvas.drawText(poi.getName(), finalX - poiMarker.getWidth() / 2,
        // finalY, textPaint);
    }
}

public void addPoint(POI point)
{
    if (point == null) return;

    for (POI p : points)
    {
        if (p.getID() == point.getID()) return;
    }

    points.add(point);
    absPoints.add(tilesManager.lonLatToPixelXY(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude()));
}

@Override
public void onClick(double longitude, double latitude)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(POIOverlay.this, Infopoi.class);

   POIOverlay.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    POIOverlay.this.finish();

    Point abs = tilesManager.lonLatToPixelXY(longitude, latitude);
    float r = poiMarker.getWidth() / 2;

    for (Point p : absPoints)
    {
        if (Math.abs(abs.x - p.x) <= r && Math.abs(abs.y - p.y) <= r)
        {

            int duration = 8;
            Toast.makeText(context, points.get(absPoints.indexOf(p)).getIcon(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
                Toast.makeText(context, points.get(absPoints.indexOf(p)).getInfo(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





            }
            return;
        }

    }

}


@Override
public void onMapZoomChanged(int zoom)
{
    absPoints.clear();
    for (POI p : points)
    {
        absPoints.add(tilesManager.lonLatToPixelXY(p.getLongitude(), p.getLatitude()));
    }

    super.onMapZoomChanged(zoom);
}
}
```

I use intent to start new activity after "pubblic void on click " but android studio report error and not start new activity why ??? Please help !!! All my attemps are failed..infopoi.class not loaded

Update ... 10/03/2015

Yes i declare in manifest... but i haven't log cat becouse i have underline all method .. in android studio ..  (POIOverlay.this, Infopoi.class) is underline red  His report this error : Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent (com.cfsv3.maps,views.overlays.POiOverlay, java.lang.Class)'  In POIOverlay.this.startActivity(myIntent); startactivity is red and error is : Cannot resolve method startActivity(android.content.Intent)' also    i try to add in public void onClick(double longitude, double latitude) implements OnClickListener i have an error in implements his report in red : Unexpected token in implements and in OnClickListener says in red Cannot resolve symbol .
Need help!

Comment: Can you post your logcat error pls ? Have you declared your Activity in the manifest file ?

Comment: Post your LogCat outputs

Comment: "HELLLPPP" would not get you anywhere on this site

Comment: What do you want to click to start new activity?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement OnClickListener

```
implements OnClickListener
```

nor did you do you set an OnClickListener

```
.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: i declare in manifest... (POIOverlay.this, Infopoi.class) is underline red  error : Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent (com.cfsv3.maps,views.overlays.POiOverlay, java.lang.Class)' In POIOverlay.this.startActivity(myIntent); startactivity is red and error is : Cannot resolve method startActivity(android.content.Intent)' also i try to add in public void onClick(double longitude, double latitude) implements OnClickListener i have an error in implements his report in red : Unexpected token in implements and in OnClickListener says in red Cannot resolve symbol . Need help!